ng-select style is broken angular 14
I added the ng-select to the application. In case I am putting the ng-select inside a mat-form-field the style of the compoents is broken:

The ng-select is encapsulated inside an angular component. This angular component implements the MatFormFieldControl, AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator.
I specified the ng-select them inside the angular.json. The css file is loaded, I checked the browser Sources:
"styles": [
              "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css",

The html code is looking in the following:
Component html code:
<div class="zg-select-container" [ngClass]="additionalClasses">
  <ng-select [items]="source"
             [bindLabel]="labelKey"
             [bindValue]="idenetifierKey"
             [placeholder]="title"
             appearance="outline"
             (change)="optionSelected($event)"
             [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  </ng-select>
</div>

The usage of the component:
      <mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="auto">
        <zg-select
          dataTestId="myarea-receipts-employee-dropdown"
          [additionalClasses]="['no-floating-label']"
          [source]="employees"
          [placeholder]="T('global.select_employee')"
          (valueChange)="onSelectedEmployeeIdChange($event)"
        ></zg-select>
      </mat-form-field>

This issue is happening only if the component is places within a mat-form-field.
Somebody has any idea what can be the issue?

I think you should use <mat-select> and not <ng-select> or is there a reason to use ng-select?
It is breaking because of the angular material styles, because you are wrapping it in a <mat-form-field> component.
If you changed it to use <mat-select>, try adding a <mat-label> above the <mat-select> instead of the setting placeholder attribute.
Check out this site for more info about the mat-select: https://v14.material.angular.io/components/select/examples

try using ngSelectMat directive: <ng-select ngSelectMat ...>

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
